# Quantum Mechanics derivation of Wallis' Formula?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Recently there was a proof of the Wallis Product using quantum mechanics on the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07813).  However, there are many proofs of the result, Wikipedia has [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

**Fine Print** the first proof has on Wikipedia, the Euler product as an input, $$\boxed{\sin \pi x = \pi x \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)}$$
and this follows from Weierstrass Factorization, which is a significant result.  One proof by [Oscar Ciaurri](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.7.693?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) circumvents this.  Another by [Lars Holst](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jap/1389370108).

**Quantum Mechanics** This derivation starts with the Hydrogen atom Schrödinger equation:

$$ H \psi = \left( - \frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2  - \frac{e^2}{r} \right) \psi = E \psi $$

Since this equation is radially symmetric there is an $SO(3)$ action on the solutions to this equation preserving the energies $E$.  So these eigenspaces can be indexed by the representations of $SO(3)$, $E_{\ell, m}$ and $\psi_{\ell , m}$.  Can we guess the values of $E$ ?

A variational approach involves minimizing as best we can, using the [point-to-line](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/analytic-geometry-topic/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line/v/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line) distance formula:
$$ E_{\ell, 0} \leq \frac{\langle \psi | H | \psi \rangle }{\langle \psi| \psi \rangle} $$
This only works for the ground state energy.

They have a guesstimate of $\langle H_\ell \rangle_{min} = \frac{1}{\ell + \frac{1}{2}}\left[ \frac{\ell!}{(\ell + \frac{1}{2})!}\right]$ while the exact answer is $E_{0, \ell} = \frac{1}{(\ell + 1)^2}$

**Bohr correspondence principle** How do we know for $\ell \gg 1$ these two values are the same?
$$ \lim_{\ell \to \infty} \frac{\langle H_\ell \rangle_{min}}{E_{0, \ell}} = 1$$
This ultimately leads to the [Wallis Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) Formula using identities of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

---

Is quantum mechanics necessary here?  I think we are using [Feynman-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem) or [Rayleigh-Ritz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Ritz_method) but I think there is something even more basic facts about Hermitian matrices as in these [notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/).

Comment: Euler's product formula for $\sin^2$ does not need the general apparatus of Weierstrass or Hadamard products: in brief, first use Liouville's theorem to prove the partial fraction expansion of $1/\sin^2 x$, second regroup and observe that this is the derivative of $\cot x$, third, observe that this is the logarithmic derivative of $\sin x$. E.g., as http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/08a_product_sine.pdf

Comment: @paulgarrett Every time I see [Liouville Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) I think **any bounded entire function is constant** "gee that's nice" -- now I see it in your [notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/notes_2014-15/08a_product_sine.pdf) and I am like wow, we get $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for free!

Comment: Yes, Liouville's theorem is _useful_, not static.

Comment: Here is a nice [commentary](http://www.rochester.edu/newscenter/discovery-of-classic-pi-formula-a-cunning-piece-of-magic-128002/) on the use of the variational principle for the spectrum of the hydrogen atom to find Wallis formula. I am a bit uncertain on what the OP is seeking; an alternative derivation of the Wallis formula? (there are many); an alternative proof using the variational principle for a Hermitian eigenvalue problem?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker could it have been done with another $H$ instead of $H = \mathbb{p}^2 + \frac{e}{r}$ ?  This argument also suggests Bohr correspondence principle and Liouville theorem are in some way analogous.

Comment: I think the observation is no big deal and has been blown out of proportion, particularly in the piece mentioned by @CarloBeenakker. The authors have two different ways of calculating some quantity, and the fact that these two ways must agree boils down to Wallis formula. It's a curiosity, and many similar ones exist.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left[\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}\right]^2=1,$$
there is no need in the Bohr's correspondence principle. Stirling's Series can be used to get $$\frac{\Gamma(z+\alpha)}{\Gamma(z+\beta)}\sim z^{\alpha-\beta},$$ as $z\to\infty$ (see, for example, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102613160 - The asymptotic expansion of a ratio of gamma functions, by A. Erdelyi and F. G. Tricomi). Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left[\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}\right]^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})n}=1.$$

P.S. This answer was inspired by Paul Garrett's comment about Watson's Lemma in this MO question: [The sum of an hydrogen atom related infinite series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245563/the-sum-of-an-hydrogen-atom-related-infinite-series)

Comment: Some other comments are given in our paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06153 (to be published in Physics Letters A).